# How to put the parent node higher than the children nodes in a drawing for a graph?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I have a tree as below.

```
Graph[{7 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

However, I want the drawing would put parent nodes at a higher position than their respective children nodes (i.e. 7 should be drawn higher than 2, instead of lower than 2). What can I do to achieve this (I don't want to specify the vertex coordinates manually)? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

1. `Graph` with the option `GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`, or
2. [`LayeredGraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LayeredGraphPlot.html), or
3. [`TreePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreePlot.html) specifying the root vertex in the third argument.

```
 Graph[{7 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   GraphLayout->"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{7 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

> same picture

```
TreePlot[{7 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5}, Automatic, 7, 
 VertexLabels-> "Name", DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

**Note:** `LayeredGraphPlot` and `TreePlot` produce `Graphics` objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
Graph[{7 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 7}]
```

[image]